# How to use fill_between()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

[image]

I have a graph and want to fill the background where the graph cross a certain value. (in my example 0.75)
I use the following code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()


df2 = pd.read_csv('kcfsinew2.csv')
x=df2['Date']
y=df2['KCFSI']
ax.plot(x, y , color='black')

theta = 0.75
ax.axhline(theta, color='grey', lw=2, alpha=0.5)
ax.fill_between(x , -1 , 6, where= y > theta ,facecolor='grey', alpha=0.5, transform=trans)
```

The image I get does not give me the expected output and I don't know what's wrong with my code.

Comment: What's `y` in your code?

Comment: Just edit my post and add y.

Comment: Try to replace the 2nd and 3d arguments with theta: `ax.fill_between(x ,theta,where=y>theta,...`

Comment: This just limited the grey area in his height..

Comment: @Dennis Please convert your question into a [minimal work example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For your particular code, please replace the `csv` file with some fictitious data such that everyone can run your example simply by copy/pasting.

Comment: Unless you provide a runnable code, it is a tough job for readers to help you here.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use the [`fill_between`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between.html) method to fill between the lines
2. Set the parameter `y2=0.75` to show where you want the bottom of the graph to be
3. Set your parameter `where=df.y > 0.75` so that it only fills above 0.75
4. Set parameters `interpolate=True` so that it fills every time the lines cross

Code example:

```
import pandas as pd # '0.23.4'
import numpy as np # '1.15.1'
import matplotlib # '2.2.3'
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns; sns.set() # '0.9.0'

# set seed
np.random.seed(1)

# make df
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(-1, 3, (30,)), index=pd.DatetimeIndex(start='20180101', periods=30, freq='3D'), columns=['y'])

# figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# plot
df.plot(figsize=(16,8), ax=ax)

# draw line
ax.axhline(0.75, color='k')

# annotate
ax.text(0, 0.75, '0.75', transform=ax.get_yaxis_transform(), ha='right', )

# fill between y=0.75 and df.y
ax.fill_between(x=df.index, y1=df.y, y2=0.75, where=df.y > 0.75, interpolate=True)

plt.show()
```

[image: graph]